# How to do Code wrapping in quarto for the whole document

Tags: quarto

Using quarto and html output, how to define `#| code-overflow: wrap` for all the code blocks in the document rather than for each code block?
Is there any way to specify the width of the cutoff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the `code-overflow` to the yaml to set as a global setting like this:

````
---
title: "Example"
format:
  html:
    code-overflow: wrap
---

```{r}
print("This is a very very very long sentence as an example to show how this execution works!")
```
````

Output:

[image]

It is explained [here](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html#code-overflow):

> To set the global default behavior use the code-overflow option